# Allow only a set number of characters in a string

Tags: c#, loops

I am working on a function that will evaluate a string and only allow x instances of each character.

For example, you can have 2 allowed character so

```
aaaabbbbbcddddd
```

would be evaluated to

```
aabbcdd
```

So far I have written this:

```
public static string removeDuplicateCharacters(String text, int allowedDuplicates)
{
    string seen="";
    foreach (char c in text){

       if(!seen.Contains(c)){
           seen = seen + c;
       } else if(seen.Contains(c)){

             // while the sting contains < allowedDuplicates
            // add c
           }
       }
    return seen; 
 }
```

I can't at the moment work out how create a while condition that is also going to count through my seen string for the number of current instances of the char currently being evaluated.

Comment: This looks like C# or Java but I won't assume. Do you have a function that can tell you how many times the character `c` appears in `seen`?

Comment: Added [tag:c#] so people able to answer this can easily find it. Feel free to correct it if it's not actually C#.

Comment: I have to make a performance note: You probably want to use a StringBuilder, not strings. Strings are immutable, every time you are appending a character you are creating a brand new string. That will be incredibly wasteful if text is very long.

Comment: This looks like a student exercise and I'm guessing that your instructor may not want you to use a dictionary. What you can use is another `foreach` loop to count the number of times `c` appears in `seen`. I don't think a `while` condition is what you really want though and don't worry if this isn't the most efficient way to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution with a `Dictionary` to keep track of the character counts:

```
public static string removeDuplicateCharacters(String text, int allowedDuplicates)
{
    string seen="";
    Dictionary<char, int> charCount = new   Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if(!charCount.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            seen += c;
            charCount.Add(c, 1);
        }
        else if(charCount[c] < allowedDuplicates)
        {
            charCount[c] += 1;
            seen += c;
        }
        else
        {
            //Reached max, do nothing
        }
    }
    return seen; 
 }
```

This is your base and you can make it as nice and fancy as you want from here.

E.g.: I would suggest a `StringBuilder` if the strings can get long as it less taxing on memory since you don't have to allocate permanently new `String`s when doing `+=` on them.

```
public static string removeDuplicateCharacters(String text, int allowedDuplicates)
{
    StringBuilder seen = new StringBuilder();

    Dictionary<char, int> charCount = new   Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if(!charCount.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            seen.Append(c);
            charCount.Add(c, 1);
        }
        else if(charCount[c] < allowedDuplicates)
        {
            charCount[c] += 1;
            seen.Append(c);
        }
        else
        {
            //Reached max, do nothing
        }
    }
    return seen.ToString(); 
 }
```

Another thing would be if you want lower and uppercase to be treated the same.
Then I would change the test to upper or lower case, but if you want to keep the casing of the original character in the return string you could do the following.

```
public static string removeDuplicateCharacters(String text, int allowedDuplicates)
{
    StringBuilder seen = new StringBuilder();

    Dictionary<char, int> charCount = new   Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        char upperCase = c.ToUpper();
        if(!charCount.ContainsKey(upperCase))
        {
            seen.Append(c);
            charCount.Add(upperCase , 1);
        }
        else if(charCount[upperCase] < allowedDuplicates)
        {
            charCount[upperCase ] += 1;
            seen.Append(c);
        }
        else
        {
            //Reached max, do nothing
        }
    }
    return seen.ToString(); 
 }
```

Just customize from here on.

Comment: Just for illustration purposes, I would expect it in production code to be removed, but since this is just an example I thought it might be helpful to the OP. If it bothers you feel free to edit it out :-)

Comment: @Bauss I hate ridiculous coding standards but I'm pretty sure there are some out there that require covering the else case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to keep track of character count

```
    public static string removeDuplicateCharacters(string text, int allowedDuplicates)
    {
        var frequency = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            int count = 1;
            if (frequency.ContainsKey(c))
                count = ++frequency[c];
            else
                frequency.Add(c, count);

            if (count <= allowedDuplicates)
                output.Append(c);
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we keep track of the seen characters and how many times we have seen them by using a `Dictionary`, and we assemble the output string with a `StringBuilder`:

```
        public static string RemoveDuplicateCharacters(string text, int allowedDuplicates)
        {
            var seen = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                int count;
                if (seen.TryGetValue(c, out count))
                {
                    count++;
                } else
                {
                    count = 1;
                }

                seen[c] = count;

                if (count <= allowedDuplicates)
                    sb.Append(c);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Test:

```
Console.WriteLine(RemoveDuplicateCharacters("aaaabbbbbcddddda", 3));
```

Output:

> aaabbbcddd

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a more appropriate approach for a beginner student. It doesn't require the use of arrays or dictionaries and sticks to simple algorithmic primitives. (I'm not objecting to their use, I just have a hunch that this is a student exercise and might even be one designed to motivate their introduction.)

```
public static string removeDuplicateCharacters(String text, int allowedDuplicates)
{
    string seen= "";
    int count = 0;
    foreach (char c in text) {
        count = 0;
        foreach (char c2 in seen) {
            if (c2 == c) count++;
        }
        if (count < allowedDuplicates) {
            seen = seen + c;
        }
    }
    return seen; 
}
```